# asp.net mvc linq I want to fetch two columns from two join table

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two tables join with PrId column, I have a view which show two columns from both tables, first column from first table and second column from second table. my actionresult is :

```
public ActionResult extrapoints()
        {
            ViewBag.dList = (from m in _session.customer
                            join p in _session.Products on m.PrId equals p.PrId
                            where m.UserId== 'john'
                             select new { FName = m.FName, price=p.price}); 


            return View();
        }
```

and in view i want to show both FName  and price, I have following view :

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.dList)
{

```
  <tr>

    <td>@item.FName </td>
    <td> @item.price</td>
   </tr>
```

}
but is show error object' does not contain a definition for FName but when i use without Fname,price like

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.dList)
{

      <tr>

        <td>@item</td>
        <td> @item</td>
       </tr>


}
```

is shows :
{ FName = Shailendra, price= 1000 }

how to solve, please help

Answer (score 0):

You Can Convert the Anonymous class to typed class, first add this class

```
  class Test
    {
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }

    }
```

and make you linq statment as

```
 ViewBag.dList = (from m in _session.customer
                            join p in _session.Products on m.PrId equals p.PrId
                            where m.UserId== 'john'
                             select new Test{ FName = m.FName, price=p.price});
```

and finally Cast the viewpage to type "Test"

```
@foreach (var item in (List<Test>)ViewBag.dList)
{

      <tr>

        <td>@item.Fname</td>
        <td> @item.price</td>
       </tr>


}
```